# Create Range of Dates in Database/Microsoft Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

In Excel, I can create a range of dates by dragging the right corner.

How can I create a range of dates in Microsoft Access/databases in general?

For example, I might want to create all the dates in 2020 in Microsoft Access, without manually typing them.

Excel Single Date

[image: Excel Single Date]

Excel Drag and Drop for Date Range

[image: Excel Drag and Drop for Date Range]

Comment: Access tables are not spreadsheets.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score -1):

You can use a *Cartesian* (multiplying) query.

First, have a tiny query that returns 10 records. Save it as **Ten**:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Abs([id] Mod 10) AS N
FROM 
    MSysObjects;
```

Then use this to generate the dates of a year:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    [Year] Short;
SELECT 
    DateSerial(IIf([Year] Between 100 And 9999,[Year],Year(Date())),1,1+[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100) AS [Date]
FROM 
    Ten AS Ten_0, 
    Ten AS Ten_1, 
    Ten AS Ten_2
WHERE 
    ((([Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100)<=DateDiff("d",DateSerial(IIf([Year] Between 100 And 9999,[Year],Year(Date())),1,1),DateSerial(IIf([Year] Between 100 And 9999,[Year],Year(Date())),12,31))))
ORDER BY 
    DateSerial(IIf([Year] Between 100 And 9999,[Year],Year(Date())),1,1+[Ten_0].[N]+[Ten_1].[N]*10+[Ten_2].[N]*100);
```